# Sort navigation programmatically before being sent to user

Tags: 2013, navigation

Below you can see the 2 images that illustrate my question.

I've a menu where it doesn't sort everything correctly. I know it sorts the categories by itself (sub-sites), (links) and so on and that is why my `A` in the menu is at the bottom.

My question is how would I best "catch" the "Menu" before it being sent to the user and then sort it all.

[This is something](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc789625(v=office.14).aspx) I tried but I can't make it work.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

[image]